# Zend Framework 2: Identical validator

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I have problem with Identical validator in ZF2. I have created following method:

```
public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if(!$this->inputFilter){
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'Int'),
                ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 32
                        )
                    )
                )
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 32
                        )
                    )
                )
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'retype-password',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 32
                        ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Identical',
                        'options' => array(
                            'token' => 'password' //I have tried $_POST['password'], but it doesnt work either
                        )
                    )
                    )
                )
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
```

Everything works fine except Identical validator which doesn't show anything(no msg, no error).
Tips are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it appears your array syntax is mis-placed is all. This should fix it for you:

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if(!$this->inputFilter){
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory = new InputFactory();

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            ),
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim')
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 32
                    )
                )
            )
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim')
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 32
                    )
                )
            )
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'retype-password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim')
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 32
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Identical',
                    'options' => array(
                        'token' => 'password' //I have tried $_POST['password'], but it doesnt work either
                    )
                )
            )
        )));

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

Comment: Oh my Goodness! It works now. Sorry for such as question. My IDE program didn't show me any errors. Thanks

Comment: No worries, simple mistake. Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes =)